# Dynamic named field names

Tags: go

I want to create a JSON response where the field name of the parent object has a dynamic name.

It is better explained with an example.

Right now, my response looks like this:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

For that I created a struct -> populate it -> return it.

My struct looks like this:

```
type Placeholder struct {
    userId    int    `json:"userId"`
    id        int    `json:"id"`
    title     string `json:"title"`
    completed bool   `json:"completed"`
}
//...
res := Placeholder{
  userId: 1,
  id: 1,
  title: "delectus aut autem",
  completed: false,
}
```

Now I want to use the userId as the field name. So I want to have this result:

```
{
  "1": {
     "id": 1,
     "title": "delectus aut autem",
     "completed": false
  }
}
```

Is there any possibility to do this in Go?

Comment: You could just build up the response you want from your data. i.e. `map[int]struct{ // Fields }` and then encode that rather than encoding your placeholder directly.

Comment: "So I want to have this result" Probably not as your "result" is not JSON. And no, you cannot use your Placeholder struct to generate this result (not even a valid JOSN) unless you want to implement MarshalJSON. Just create a map, use userID as key and omit UserID during marshaling Placeholder.

Comment: Create it with map and it works fine. Ty guys

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the datatype of `res` from `Placeholder` to `map[int]Placeholder`.

```
userId := 1
res := map[int]Placeholder{
    userId: {
        id:        1,
        title:     "delectus aut autem",
        completed: false,
    },
}
fmt.Printf("%v", res)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/rCBl2r7fQTe

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a struct with `json:",inline"`.

**NOTE:** do not omit errors in real code!

```golang
type Placeholder struct {
    ID        int    `json:"id"`
    Title     string `json:"title"`
    Completed bool   `json:"completed"`
}

type PlaceholderWithUserID struct {
    UserID      int `json:"userId"`
    Placeholder `json:",inline"`
}

type PlaceholderMap map[int]Placeholder

func main() {
    var res PlaceholderWithUserID
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"userId": 1, "id": 1, "title": "delectus aut autem", "completed": false}`), &res)
    mapping := PlaceholderMap{
        res.UserID: res.Placeholder,
    }
    out, _ := json.Marshal(mapping)
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

[Playgorund](https://play.golang.org/p/I1WAygi3QKq)